# Why do I get an error when I use tipo from template<class tipo> in a function?

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++ with some videos, but for some reason when I put `tipo` from `template <class tipo>` in a function, it suddenly gives me lots of errors.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class tipo>
void dar( tipo dato );

int main(){
    int dat1 = 345;
    float dat2 = 4.435;
    char dat3 = 'a';

    dar( dat1 );
    dar( dat2 );
    dar( dat3 );

    return 0;
}

void dar( tipo dato ){   
    cout<<"el dato es: "<<dato;
}
```

The [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZGbJ.png) are:
[image]

Comment: And what did the errors say? Which part of the error messages are unclear to you? Can you [edit] your question and add additional information to it.

Comment: You also need the template specification when you actually define `dar`, not just when you forward declare it.

Comment: Your definition must also be a template. Usually, programmers define templates right when they are declared

Comment: I believe more research could have been conducted before asking this question. Checking out documentation (e.g. c++ reference) or even a short blog article on templates in c++ would have likely yielded an answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is a forward declaration:

```
template <class tipo>
void dar( tipo dato );
```

And this is supposed to be the definition:

```
void dar( tipo dato ){   
    cout<<"el dato es: "<<dato;
}
```

But it isn't. Instead it's a function (not a function template) taking a `tipo` by value. There is no type called `tipo` in the program.

You need to make `tipo` a template parameter:

```
template <class tipo>
void dar( tipo dato ){   
    cout<<"el dato es: "<<dato;
}
```

An easier way to do it is to provide the definition directly at the beginning of the program and skip the forward declaration:

```
#include <iostream>

// using namespace std; // don't use this even though the video used it. See:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

template <class tipo>
void dar( tipo dato ) {
    std::cout << "el dato es: " << dato << '\n';
}

int main(){
    int dat1 = 345;
    float dat2 = 4.435;
    char dat3 = 'a';

    dar( dat1 );
    dar( dat2 );
    dar( dat3 );
}
```